# Is there any non-constant entire function $f$ such that $f(z) = f(-z)$ and $f(z + \tau) = f(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Since $f(z) = f(-z)$, then we can see that the odd-degree coefficients in the series expansion of $f$ around 0 must vanish, so $f$ can be written as 
$$f(z) = h(z^2)$$
for some entire function $h$; then since $f(z + \tau) = f(z)$ for all $z$, we have
$$h\left((z+\tau)^2\right) = h\left(z^2\right)$$
for all $z$, so $h$ is constant on sets of the form $\{(z + n\tau)^2 : n \in \mathbb Z\}$. Does this mean that $h$ must be constant, and therefore $f$ is constant?

Comment: How about $\cos z$, for a suitable $\tau$?

Comment: Take f(z)=cos(z) and tau = 2pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no loss of generality to choose $\tau$ to be your favourite
complex number, so I choose $\tau=2\pi$. The $2\pi$-periodic entire functions
all have the form
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{inz}.$$
Such a function is even iff $a_n=a_{-n}$ so the general even
function will be
$$f(z)=a_0+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(e^{inz}+e^{-inz})
=a_0+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos nz.$$
The most obvious non-constant example is $f(z)=\cos z$.